# Bluetooth mouse quit functioning after lion 10.7.2 update

Tags: macbook-pro, bluetooth, macos

I will be as short yet detailed possible.  The devices are Microsoft IntelliMouse Bluetooth mouse and keyboard.  The keyboard still works.  The mouse no longer works properly since I updated from lion 10.7.1 to 10.7.2. The keyboard connects and pairs, the mouse will "connect" during the initial setup but never shows the status "paired," although I never noticed if it was "paired" in the past.  The mouse works during the initial setup.  It will also work 50% of the time if I just press the sync button on the bottom of the mouse.  Each time it works until the connection is lost due to inactivity and then its down again until I perform one of those previous two steps.  In the bluetooth status bar the mouse and keyboard both show up as system devices.  When I first click the mouse during a period of inactivity it alerts bluetooth, in the status of the menu bar the "Microsoft Mouse" becomes bold as if the device is connected, but there is never activity from the mouse.

I have already tried the following.

1. Remove Bluetooth with bluetooth manager and re-setup (restart in between)
2. Remove via bluetooth preferences pane and re-setup (restart in between)
3. Reset SMC
4. Reset PRAM
5. unchecked the box "allow bluetooth devices to wake this computer" (it was already checked so I tried both ways)
6. Clean install of Lion 10.7.2
7. I tried completely removing all microsoft drivers (100% during the lion CLEAN install) and it is still broken.  Unfortunately the copy of lion I have is from the Mac App store and it is 10.7.2.
8. I have removed and reinstalled every way I can think, by mouse preference pane, bluetooth manager, bluetooth pref pane, etc...
9. Actually this is the first thing I did, but I changed the batteries with three new sets just to be certain.
10. Tried pairing in the bluetooth manager

I have browsed google and some forums and can't figure out a fix.  Based on the console files, I suspect that Lion's blued is expecting some sort of passphrase from the mouse but it is a mouse?  It does not have a passphrase and never has from what I remember.  I will show the console errors, if someone knows how I can assign a passphrase or give the bluetooth daemon the setting no passphrase required for the mouse device type, I think that might fix the problem.  In the meantime I will look for how to manually add a bluetooth device in OSX.

Console errors, these occur not when I first click the mouse from a disconnected state, but after 15-20 seconds after the connection fails:

```
Nov  6 00:13:09 harrys-MacBook kernel[0]: [SendHCIRequestFormatted] ### ERROR: [0x0411] (Authentication Requested) -- Send request failed (err = 0x0010 (kBluetoothHCIErrorHostTimeout))
Nov  6 00:13:09 harrys-MacBook kernel[0]: [SendHCIRequestFormatted] ### ERROR: [0x080D] (Write Link Policy Settings) -- Send request failed (err = 0x0002 (kBluetoothHCIErrorNoConnection))
Nov  6 00:13:09 harrys-MacBook kernel[0]: [SendHCIRequestFormatted] ### ERROR: [0x0C37] (Write Link Supervision Timeout) -- Send request failed (err = 0x0002 (kBluetoothHCIErrorNoConnection))
Nov  6 00:13:23 harrys-MacBook kernel[0]: [SendHCIRequestFormatted] ### ERROR: [0x0405] (Create Connection) -- Send request failed (err = 0x0004 (kBluetoothHCIErrorPageTimeout))
Nov  6 00:13:23 harrys-MacBook kernel[0]: [SendHCIRequestFormatted] ### ERROR: [0x040C] (Link Key Request Negative Reply) -- Send request failed (err = 0x0002 (kBluetoothHCIErrorNoConnection))
Nov  6 00:32:40 harrys-MacBook kernel[0]: [SendHCIRequestFormatted] ### ERROR: [0x0411] (Authentication Requested) -- Send request failed (err = 0x0010 (kBluetoothHCIErrorHostTimeout))
Nov  6 00:32:40 harrys-MacBook kernel[0]: [SendHCIRequestFormatted] ### ERROR: [0x080D] (Write Link Policy Settings) -- Send request failed (err = 0x0002 (kBluetoothHCIErrorNoConnection))
Nov  6 00:32:40 harrys-MacBook kernel[0]: [SendHCIRequestFormatted] ### ERROR: [0x0C37] (Write Link Supervision Timeout) -- Send request failed (err = 0x0002 (kBluetoothHCIErrorNoConnection))
Nov  6 00:32:48 harrys-MacBook kernel[0]: [SendHCIRequestFormatted] ### ERROR: [0x0C20] (Write Authentication Enable) -- Send request failed (err = 0xE00002ED (kIOReturnNotResponding))
Nov  6 00:33:01 harrys-MacBook kernel[0]: [SendHCIRequestFormatted] ### ERROR: [0x0405] (Create Connection) -- Send request failed (err = 0x0004 (kBluetoothHCIErrorPageTimeout))
Nov  6 00:33:01 harrys-MacBook kernel[0]: [SendHCIRequestFormatted] ### ERROR: [0x040C] (Link Key Request Negative Reply) -- Send request failed (err = 0x0002 (kBluetoothHCIErrorNoConnection))
```

Bluetooth system information:

```
Apple Bluetooth Software Version:   4.0.1f4
  Hardware Settings:
  Address:  00-1e-52-d2-cf-91
  Manufacturer: Cambridge Silicon Radio
  Name: harry’s MacBook
  Firmware Version: 1965
  Bluetooth Power:  On
  Discoverable: No
  Vendor ID:    0x5ac
  Product ID:   0x8205
  HCI Version:  3 (0x3)
  HCI Revision: 1965 (0x7ad)
  LMP Version:  3 (0x3)
  LMP Subversion:   1965 (0x7ad)
  Device Type (Major):  Computer
  Device Type (Complete):   Mac Portable
  Composite Class Of Device:    3801356 (0x3a010c)
  Device Class (Major): 1 (0x1)
  Device Class (Minor): 3 (0x3)
  Service Class:    464 (0x1d0)
  Services:
  Bluetooth File Transfer:
  Folder other devices can browse:  ~/Public
  Requires Authentication:  Yes
  State:    Enabled
  Bluetooth File Exchange:
  Folder for accepted items:    ~/Downloads
  Requires Authentication:  No
  When other items are accepted:    Ask
  When PIM items are accepted:  Ask
  When receiving items: Prompt for each file
  State:    Enabled
  Devices (Paired, Favorites, etc):
  Microsoft Keyboard:
  Address:  00-0d-3a-a4-f2-b6
  Type: Keyboard
  Firmware Version: 0x10
  Services: Microsoft¬Æ Keyboard Elite for Bluetooth¬Æ
  Paired:   Yes
  Favorite: No
  Connected:    Yes
  Manufacturer: Broadcom (0x2, 0x100)
  Vendor ID:    0x45e
  Product ID:   0x99
  EDR Supported:    No
  eSCO Supported:   No
  Incoming Serial Ports:
  Bluetooth-PDA-Sync:
  RFCOMM Channel:   3
  Requires Authentication:  No
  Outgoing Serial Ports:
  Bluetooth-Modem:
  Address:  
  RFCOMM Channel:   0
  Requires Authentication:  No
```

Comment: Just to rule out the obvious: Did you put fresh batteries into the mouse? Did you try to re-pair the  mouse with the Mac?

Comment: I have the same problem, as soon my computer sleeps the mouse will lose the connection. This worked perfectly in snowleopard but fail's in Lion. the preferences of bluetooth sais that this device is not paired.

Comment: Thanks for this thorough documentation of your problem. Now the obvious question: Have you contacted Microsoft tech support and asked them if they know of any issues?

Comment: Did you get any feedback on this, I am having similar problems with bluetooth mice (Rocketfish and Gear Head brands I tried)